# Find first invisible block by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div style="display:block">Text</div>
<div style="display:block">Text</div>
<div style="display:none">Text</div>
<div style="display:none">Text</div>
<div style="display:none">Text</div>
```

**How do I find first invisible block and make it visible?**

If there is no invisible block, do nothing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('div:hidden:first').show();
```

- `div` the [`element-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)
- `:hidden` the [`hidden-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)
- `:first` the [`first-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$('div:hidden:first').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selectors:

```
$('#wrapperContainer > div:hidden:first').show();
```

(Recommend a wrapper container because if you just do 'div:hidden:first' it will get the first hidden div on the page, which probably isn't what you want)